# Send keyboard input while session is disconnected

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I have a task that I want to automate that basically requires running a GUI application, and sending it keypress input.

I have a powershell that works for that purpose (though anything that uses out of the box windows functionality would be fine as well).

The issue is that I need this to run unattended, and when I disconnect the session, it stops the ability of the script to send input (or maybe it prevents the app from having focus?)

I am looking for a way to have this process run without an active session, or a way to "trick" windows into keeping the session active even after the RDP connection is disconnected.

A test script that can be used for this purpose is (requires opening notepad first):

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
while ($true) {
    $wshell.AppActivate('Untitled - Notepad');
    $d = date;
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($d);
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');
    start-sleep 1
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't take action on a GUI without a logged-on user identity that owns it. GUI's only runs in the context of the active logged-on user session. PowerShell requires a user context. This is an OS operational boundary. Disconnecting from RDP, drops the user context, forces a log off.

Comment: Is there any way to keep the user context? I tried RDP to box 1, and the RDP from box 1 to box 2, and logging off of box 1 dropped the user context on box 2 as well. My best workaround for now is to use an RDP client on Linux that doesn't do that, but that seems terrible

Comment: Sessions from one RDP to another on Windows are dependencies. So, there is no way I am aware of accomplishing what you are after in Windows. Frankly, this would be a security issue, if one could start a session on one host, hop to another, start one, and disconnect from the previous. As a security type, I'd immediately shut that down/block it altogether. So, If I were you, I'd check with your risk management team first, before continuing down their path at all. As it coudl come back to bite you hard.

Comment: Spoke to security about creating a VM that did just this (with just this application installed) and nothing else. Tentatively, the only solution we've found is to open up the RDP session from Linux, where the RDP client doesn't disconnect just because someone has disconnected from the Linux host.